# Laravel: Call to undefined method save()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to update all my records where the name is like the one im referencing it.

However im getting an error saying **Call to undefined method save()**

**Here's my code**

```
$section = Section1::where('name', 'like', 'ss123')->get();
      $section->name = Input::get('name');
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 4):

`$section = Section1::where('name', 'like', 'ss123')->get()` returns a collection (think of an `array`).

Therefore you should loop through the collection using `foreach` and apply the save to each object in the collection, as such:

```
foreach($section as $s)
{
     $s->name = Input::get('name');
     $s->update(); 
}
```

Then again this ain't very DB-friendly.

Therefore, the most appropriate action in your case will be a mass update:

`Section1::where('name','like','ss1213')->update(['name'=>Input::get('name')]);`

Answer (score 0):

try `dd($section)` and find the available method to prevent call the undefined method.

I assume you are using `$section->save();`

if you want to update, 
use `$section->touch();`
or `$section->update(array('name' => Input::get'name'));`